# RecyclerView in Android -- set view gone is useless

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When I use `RecyclerView` with `LinearLayoutManager` which sets orientation as horizontal and then set adapter to `RecyclerView`. At the same time, I set RecyclerView's visibility as `View.GONE`.

But a strange thing would happen when I call `adapter.notifyItemInserted` or any other method like this, the `RecyclerView` would change to `View.VISIBLE`.

Why this happened and how can I fix this?

Comment: you set the `RecyclerView` to `GONE` or one of the rows to `GONE`?

Comment: I call this method : recyclerview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Answer (score 1):

the problem doesn't exist.

I am so sorry that I made a mistake in my app to make Recyclerview become visible.